# How do you pass concrete (non-type) Generic parameters in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust

In C++, I can make a struct that takes a compile-time capacity argument, such as,

```cpp
template <size_t capacity>
struct Foo {
  uint8_t data[capacity];
};
```

This is useful, for example, to pre-allocate a compile-time variable amount of space on the stack and avoid heap allocation.

How do I do the same in Rust?  This doesn't compile:

```rust
pub struct UStr<capacity> {
    data: [u8; capacity],
}

/*
error[E0423]: expected value, found type parameter `capacity`
 --> src/demo.rs:2:13
  |
2 |     data: [u8; capacity],
  |                ^^^^^^^^ not a value
*/
```

Comment: This is not yet supported on stable Rust, but [will probably be supported soon](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2000-const-generics.md).